# how to draw lines in Pine script (Tradingview)?

Tags: line, finance, pine-script

Pine editor still does not have built-in functions to plot lines (such as support lines, trend lines).
I could not find any direct or indirect method to draw lines. 
I want to build function that look like below (for example only)

```
draw_line(price1, time1,price2, time2)
```

any Ideas or suggestions ?

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately I don't think this is something they want to provide. Noticing several promising posts from 4 years ago that never came through. The only other way, seem to involve some calculations, by approximating your line with some line plots, where you hide the non-relevant parts.

For [example](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Annotation_Functions_Overview):

```
...
c = close >= open ? lime : red
plot(close, color = c)
```

would produce something like this:

[image]

Then, you could try to replace `red` with `na` to get only the green parts.

**Example 2**

I've done some more experiments. Apparently Pine is so crippled you can't even put a plot in function, so the only way seem to be to use the point slope formula for a line, like this:

```js
//@version=3
study(title="Simple Line", shorttitle='AB', overlay=true)

P1x = input(5744)
P1y = input(1.2727)
P2x = input(5774)
P2y = input(1.2628)
plot(n, color=na, style=line)   // hidden plot to show the bar number in indicator

// point slope
m = - (P2y - P1y) / (P2x - P1x)

// plot range
AB = n < P1x or n > P2x ? na : P1y - m*(n - P1x)
LA = (n == P1x) ? P1y : na
LB = (n == P2x) ? P2y : na

plot(AB, title="AB", color=#ff00ff, linewidth=1, style=line, transp=0)
plotshape(LA, title='A', location=location.absolute, color=silver, transp=0, text='A', textcolor=black, style=shape.labeldown)
plotshape(LB, title='B', location=location.absolute, color=silver, transp=0, text='B', textcolor=black, style=shape.labelup )
```

The result is quite nice, but too inconvenient to use.
[image]

---

**UPDATE:** 2019-10-01

Apparently they have added some new line functionality to *Pinescript* `4.0+`.
Here is an example of using the new **`vline()`** function:

```js
//@version=4
study("vline() Function for Pine Script v4.0+", overlay=true)

vline(BarIndex, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) => // Verticle Line, 54 lines maximum allowable per indicator
    return = line.new(BarIndex, -1000, BarIndex, 1000, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth)

if(bar_index%10==0.0)
    vline(bar_index, #FF8000ff, line.style_solid, 1) // Variable assignment not required
```

As for the other "new" line function, I have not tested it yet.

Answer (score 6):

This is now possible in [Pine Script v4](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/introducing-pine-script-4-12626/):

[image: Preview]

```java
//@version=4
study("Line", overlay=true)
l = line.new(bar_index, high, bar_index[10], low[10], width = 4)
line.delete(l[1])
```

Here is a vertical line function by midtownsk8rguy on TradingView:

```java
vline(BarIndex, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) => // Verticle Line Function, ≈50-54 lines maximum allowable per indicator
    // return = line.new(BarIndex,   0.0, BarIndex,     100.0, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) // Suitable for study(overlay=false) and RSI, Stochastic, etc...
    // return = line.new(BarIndex,  -1.0, BarIndex,       1.0, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) // Suitable for study(overlay=false) and +/-1.0 oscillators
    return = line.new(BarIndex, low - tr, BarIndex, high + tr, xloc.bar_index, extend.both, Color, LineStyle, LineWidth) // Suitable for study(overlay=true)

if(bar_index%10==0.0) // Generically plots a line every 10 bars
    vline(bar_index, #FF8000ff, line.style_solid, 1) // Variable assignment not required
```

You can also use `if barstate.islast` if you only draw your lines once instead of on each candle, this way you don't need to `delete` the previous lines.

Comment: Small thing: the x axis (time) only accepts integers. (first and third argument) (bar_index is an integer), in some way it makes sense but I wasn't expecting it when trying to use a moving average (this one returns floats for x)

Comment: You can also use `if barstate.islast` if you only draw your lines once instead of on each candle, this way you don't need to `delete` the previous lines.

Answer (score 1):

More compact code for draw lines:

```js
//@version=3
study("Draw line", overlay=true)

plot(n, color=na, style=line)
AB(x1,x2,y1,y2) => n < x1 or n > x2 ? na : y1 + (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (n - x1)

plot(AB(10065,10136,3819,3893), color=#ff00ff, linewidth=1, style=line, 
transp=0)
plot(AB(10091,10136,3966.5,3931), color=#ff00ff, linewidth=1, style=line, 
transp=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might answer the original question:

```
//@version=4
study(title="trendline example aapl", overlay=true)

//@AAPL
line12= line.new(x1=int(1656322200000), 
y1=float(143.49), 
x2=int(1659519000000), 
y2=float(166.59), 
extend=extend.right, 
xloc=xloc.bar_time)
```

(to calculate the time it needs to be calculated as the *bar open time in unix milliseconds see: https://currentmillis.com/ ; can be calculated in excel with this formula =
= (([date eg mm/dd/yyyy]+[bar open time eg 9.30am])- 0/24 - DATE(1970,1,1)) * 86400000
= ((6/27/2022+9:30:00 AM)- 0/24 - DATE(1970,1,1)) * 86400000
= ((44739+0.395833333333333)- 0/24 - DATE(1970,1,1)) * 86400000
= 1656322200000
)
adjust the zero/24 to offset the time zone if needed eg 1/24